# How to get field type using Jackson ObjectMapper?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Any idea how to retrieve Java type for given json path based on Jackson's ObjectMapper object and particular Class?

Let's say we have

```
class User {
    String fullName;
    Integer age;
    Boolean active;
    // ...
}
class Account {
    @JsonProperty("accountOwner")
    User owner;
    // ...
}
```

and Jackson's ObjectMapper I'd like to find a way to deserialize String value to object of type represented by the field on given path (or at least get its type), e.g.

- given "/accountOwner/age" and "25" get 25 (of type Integer)
- given "/accountOwner/active" and "true" get true (of type Boolean)
- given "/accountOwner/fullName" and "Johny Bravo" get "Johny Bravo" String
- etc ...

Comment: Can you share a sample JSON?

Comment: There's no json. I just want to deserialize, or at least know the type of a single field given by json path based on ObjectMapper and type/class.

Comment: You can build a Json schema to get the type information of the certain field. https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema/

Answer (score 0):

I have an example here:

```
User user = new User();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
     user = mapper.readValue(new File("D:\\json.txt"), User.class);
    System.out.println("user : " + user);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My bean:

```
public class User {
    String fullName;
    Integer age;
    Boolean active;
    /**
     * @return the fullName
     */
    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }
    /**
     * @param fullName the fullName to set
     */
    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the age
     */
    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    /**
     * @param age the age to set
     */
    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    /**
     * @return the active
     */
    public Boolean getActive() {
        return active;
    }
    /**
     * @param active the active to set
     */
    public void setActive(Boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [fullName=" + fullName + ", age=" + age + ", " +
                "active=" + active + "]";
    }
}
```

And finally the Json object (json.txt):

```
{"fullName":"Pedro Gamarra","age":30,"active":true}
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. I don't have any json to read btw. Please read the q. more carefully.